# Appending points to PCD in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, numpy, three.js, point-clouds

I am new to ThreeJS and I wanted to merge a .pcd file to another, without losing the RBG values for both of the files. For example, if file1.pcd has RGB values of (1,0,0) and file2.pcd has RGB values of (0,0,1), when I merge them, the resulting pcd should be a pcd having both the points of pcd merged without losing the color values.

Comment: Could you please clarify which platform you are interested in merging the point clouds: ThreeJS or Open3D?

Comment: I am trying to merge the point clouds in ThreeJS